# Split a number into n numbers

Tags: algorithms

I have to develop an algorithm that splits a number into n parts.

For example, if I have to split 12 in 3 numbers, I will have this: (4, 4, 4).

But if I have to split 11 in 3 numbers, I will have this: (4, 4, 3).

And 10 in 3 numbers, I will have: (4, 3, 3)

The different between the number and in the numbers split must be 0 or 1.

Is there any mathematical formula to do it?

Comment: *Hint:* 11 divided by 3 is 3 with a remainder of 2.

Comment: Thanks. While I was making the bed I thought that I could use the remainder... Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To distribute the number $n$ into $p$ parts, you would calculate the
“truncating integer division”  of $n$ divided by $p$, and the
corresponding remainder.

Mathematically that is (assuming that both $n$ and $p$ are strictly
positive integers)
$$
 d = \left\lfloor \frac np \right\rfloor \, , \quad r = n \bmod p = n-pd \, .
$$

In many programming languages you would do something like

```
int d = n / p; // truncating integer division
int r = n % p; // remainder
```

Then $$n = pd + r = r(d+1) + (p-r)d $$
so that the desired partition is 
$$
 \underbrace{d+1, \ldots, d+1}_{r \text{ times}}, \underbrace{d, \ldots, d}_{p-r \text{ times}}
$$

Comment: this produces unbalanced parts

Comment: @jangorecki: What exactly do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: sorry, it does work! thank you very much